# how to extract token from string in python?

Tags: python, regex

I'm pretty new to Python and I know Perl can do this, but I haven't found it in Python yet.
What I'm trying to do is to extract a token from a line.

```
p = re.compile('555=\d+')
ID = p.findall(line)
```

where line is a single line in a file, and the digits after 555= should be recorded. However, with these two lines, I can only get things like 555=1234567, what I really want is 1234567. Can anyone help and suggest a solution?
Thanks!

Comment: use the `search` method (for only one match) instead of `findall` (for several matches). You must put your pattern into a raw string `r'555=\d+'` or escape the backslashes `'555=\\d+'`. If you want to only extract the value on the right, use a capture group or, why not a lookbehind (but it's slower).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `()` to capture what you want:

```
>>> p = re.compile('555=(\d+)')
>>> p.findall("555=1234567")
['1234567']
```

> **(...)**
>
> Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses,
>   and indicates the start and end of a group; the contents of a group
>   can be retrieved after a match has been performed, and can be matched
>   later in the string with the \number special sequence
>
> [ref](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should capture the expression you want using "()".
So your expression should be `p = re.compile('555=(\d+)')`